# Dual-Boot(on different hard drives) problem after windows update to firmware

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've set up a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04.03 on SSD and Windows 10 on HDD. Everything was going well, then a few days ago windows updated the firmware of the MSI laptop. Since then, I'm not able to boot properly. Every time, I get stuck at the grub terminal

[image]

Then, I  need to reboot from here and press f12 which leads to a screen

> > > checking media presence ......

After some time, the grub menu appears showing both ubuntu and windows on its list.

I've tried updating grub after entering into ubuntu, but it didn't help. I've UEFI enabled boot. Can, someone please help me on this problem?

Comment: UEFI update resets some settings to defaults. Did it change AHCI back or change default boot order? Or change UEFI/BIOS boot mode. I have to keep a list of UEFI settings I change. While probably UEFI settings related. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This is the boot-repair's boot-info summary `http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zvXYCZn9zb/`

Comment: Boot-Repair mentions you have UEFI Secure Boot on? Did you install Ubuntu with it on? If not that is the issue. Turn off Secure Boot , but still boot in UEFI mode. I do prefer to have an ESP - efi system partition on the Linux drive. You are booting Ubuntu on sda via the ESP on sdb.

Comment: Yes, My ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: Have you tried with UEFI Secure Boot off, but UEFI on. Do not turn on legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode.

Comment: I wiil try tomorrow and update.